# Update an array after submit a form in another component

Tags: angular, components

I have a component called "modal-form" and another called "array" and I would like to update the array after the submit of the form without refresh the view. I tried to use `@Input` but it didn't seem to work when I called a test function from modal component.

modal-form

Here I post the form but I refresh the view, this is not what I'm looking for.

```
  add() {
    this.service.post(this.form).subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(data)
      this.router.navigate([this.router.url]);
    });
  }
```

array

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
        this.service.getObjects().subscribe((data) => {
          this.objects = data;
        });
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the ideal situation for using a service. Either you have a local variable in a service (`stuffArray` for example), or you set up a Subject-as-a-Service: generally a `BehaviorSubject` which your array component subscribes to. Either way, you save to the array (or have the `BehaviorSubject` emit) when you save the form in the modal. For full safety, do so in the callback from the server request, to make sure the data has saved correctly.

Comment: How do you set the `BehaviorSubject` in service function ? When I set my variable I get this error : `Type 'Observable<[]>' is missing the following properties from type 'BehaviorSubject<[]>`

Comment: `const mySubj$ = new BehaviorSubject<T>(initialValue)`

Comment: You can't just assign the HTTP request as a BehaviorSubject. If you want to use that approach, I suggest you read up about it first.